# locus of points from which a given segment AB subtends a given angle of alpha

Tags: geometry

in euclidean geometry  the locus of points from which a given segment AB subtends a given angle of alpha is made of two arc of circles(https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par_de_arcos_capazes).what is his locus in non euclidean geometry(spherical/ taxicab/hyperbolic). in portuguese, this locus is called aerco apaz. chat gpts says that in english the locus is called "apollonius circle",is this correct?

[image]